# newsapi.org does not display the content and url of the news.google.com image | NEWS API

Tags: java, android, google-news, newsapi

When making a request to the API the return I get is this:

```
{
            "source": {
                "id": "google-news",
                "name": "Google News"
            },
            "author": "Euronews em Português",
            "title": "Ataque a escola no Uganda faz mais de 40 mortos - Euronews em Português",
            "description": null,
            "url": "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CCAiC2tBdTJOS2dsTE9ZmAEB?oc=5",
            "urlToImage": null,
            "publishedAt": "2023-06-17T15:02:09Z",
            "content": null
        }
```

`content` and `urlToImage` always receive NULL. I would like to use the `excludeDomain` function but it is not working with the domain news.google.com

I want to know how I can delete the domain from Google, but for that I need to know the actual domain.